# Azure Remove User Consent to API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

From my frontend application, when I request an access token I pass two scopes that need to be returned with the token.

I did not grant the application these consent in the Azure Portal. Instead the user has to explicitely give consent from the popup window.

Once the user has granted consent, I get the access token with the required scopes.

But how do I revoke consent from the Azure Portal ?  And how can I see which user has granted consent ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can go to Enterprise Applications -> Find your app -> Permissions tab -> User consent tab.

There you can see which permissions users have consented to, for example:

[image: Permissions tab]

You can then click Review permissions -> This app has more permissions than I want.
This will give you a PowerShell script that you can run to remove all user consent for that app. It can of course be customized to only remove certain permissions.

Currently there is no UI features to remove consented permissions, PowerShell/Graph API is the only way.

Comment: Thanks for that. Indeed it seems to be the way. The strange thing is that when I execute the powershell script, I get an error on second line  Resource 'guid of the objectId' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present. How is that possible since the guid is correct ?

Comment: Hmm, could the user have been deleted who that consent was given to?

Comment: no, and the objectId is the one of the application, not the user's

Comment: wait, got it. I had to specify the correct TenantId when using Connect-AzureAD. Working now :)

Comment: That is correct, this article also can helps https://www.domstamand.com/removing-user-consent-from-an-azure-ad-application/

Comment: Sorry to vent. It seems super weird that there is no web UI and that powershell is the closest to a no-code solution. If a UI lets you consent there should be a UI-based way to revoke. Not the venue. I know. Downvote away.

Comment: For me it was "Enterprise App" -> "My App.." -> "Users and groups" -> Choose relevant user and remove.