# Teams Bot Access permissions reset

Tags: c#, permissions, botframework, single-sign-on

I am following the tutorial to accomplish SSO with chat bot in Teams, SBS bots with SSO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-bots-with-sso?tutorial-step=5

At "Test in Web chat" section in Azure, I authenticated and then got the access permission window request displayed:

[image]

I accepted the request and got the token.
It seems this permissions consent window will be displayed only once and never again.
As I am testing this feature I would like to reset these permissions to visualise the flow again without needing to create/use a new account every time to sign in in Teams.
Is it possible to reset the permissions granted? So the permissions request window can be displayed again.

Comment: I believe you need to revoke User consent to the App in Azure AD. This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444298/2233543 has the information you need.